# iOS FCM push notification not received if app is terminated

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on a Swift project and integrating FCM into it. I am able to receive push notification when app is running as well as when app is in background state. But sometimes when I terminate (force close) the app, then on sending notification from console, no notification is shown.

I am working on iOS 10 and implemented below code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { granted, error in
     if error == nil {
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()

            if granted {
                print("Notification access true!")
            } else {
                print("Notification access false") 
            }
      }
}
```

I have also implemented UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate and it's methods.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler([.alert,.badge, .sound])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

        print(userInfo)

        self.handleOnNotifClick()

        completionHandler()
}
```

It only happens when the app is force closed from recently used apps drawer. Please look into it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When your app is terminated, notifications are not delivered to your app delegate. If the notification contains an alert payload, this will be displayed.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11.But I am already sending data in alert. Still notification is not shown.

Comment: is it receiving in foreground mode?

Comment: Yes @GaneshKumar. In Foreground mode, I am able to receive the notification.

Comment: in background mode too?

Comment: yes. Not receiving in terminated/suspended/force killed mode only.

Comment: show us the full `appdelegate` file

Comment: Hi. Did you set the payload `priority` to `"high"`?

Comment: Yes @AL. Priority is set to high.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!!

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    let state: UIApplicationState = UIApplication.shared.applicationState

    if state == .active{
        if let notification = userInfo["aps"] as? [AnyHashable: Any],
            let alert = notification["alert"] as? String {
            print(alert)
            let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
            localNotification.alertBody = alert
            localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
            UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
        }
    }else if state == .inactive{

        if let notification = userInfo["aps"] as? [AnyHashable: Any],let alert = notification["alert"] as? String {
            print(alert)
            let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
            localNotification.alertBody = alert
            localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
            UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)

        }
    }else if state == .background{
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

        if let notification = userInfo["aps"] as? [AnyHashable: Any],let alert = notification["alert"] as? String,let sound = notification["sound"] as? String{
            print(alert)
            var localNotification = UILocalNotification()
            localNotification.alertBody = alert
            localNotification.soundName = sound
            UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve for when the app has been terminated

Comment: did you try FCM console for send message ?

Comment: If it's receive message then you must change your server side for receive notification while background

Comment: The OP specified that the app state is `terminated` not `background`

Comment: check with console. if it's work then add           content_available: true,
          mutable_content: true in data at your notification server file